# DEP preventing my COM DLL from working

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-7, intraweb

I'm trying to use a COM DLL (written in Delphi 7) within my Delphi 7 IntraWeb application but it's failing due to DEP. I'm pretty much certain it's DEP that is preventing me from using the DLL because if I compile and run my IntraWeb app as a StandAlone Server, everything works fine. But, compiling and runnning it as an ISAPI DLL, it fails.

On WinXP (using IIS 6) I can add DllHost.exe to DEP and everything works. Of course, I really don't want to do that. On Win7/2008 (IIS 7) this isn't an option.

Can someone point me in a direction that can help me get my COM DLL to work when called from an IntraWeb ISAPI DLL?

Do I need to do something to the COM DLL? Are there any permissions I can add somewhere?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: DEP is usually really a sign that you have a memory access bug. Fix that and the DEP modification isn't needed.

Comment: See if [the fix](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/23411) mentioned in [this QC report](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=12151) helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but neither resulted in any success. I even created a new Intraweb app with only a button click which tried to connect to the DLL and it too failed. I even bypassed the DLL and went directly to the web service (which the DLL does) and that failed as well. Again, compiling as a StandAlone Server works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

i would host the dll inside a local executable, calling methods until the crash happens. You would do this with DEP enabled on your own machine.

Unfortunately Delphi 7 *itself* crashes with Data Execution Prevention enabled, in addition to memory violations in the RTL/VCL that TOndrej mentioned.

That is what you'll need to do to get your COM dll working with DEP - find the bugs and fix them.