# AV trying to access WSDL method from Intraweb ISAPI DLL

Tags: web-services, delphi, delphi-7, isapi, intraweb

Delphi 7 Pro
Intraweb 7.2

I'm trying to get a webservice to work within an Intraweb ISAPI DLL.

I've consumed the webservice which works perfectly when I run my project as a Standalone Application but fails with an AV when I run my project as an ISAPI DLL.

I can successfully instantiate the Soap object (in both the SA and ISAPI) but when I try to access any of the methods from the Soap object using the ISAPI DLL, I get an AV - again, calling the same method from the Standalone App works perfectly.

Is there something special I need to do with IIS, permission wise or anything, that can help me resolve this?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: A wild guess: maybe the AV is caused by a violation of Data Execution Prevention (DEP), if the web server has a different DEP setting than the standalone app

Comment: Being this is an ISAPI DLL, I really don't want to alter and DEP settings. I've even asked this same question but with a DEP flavor [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502036/dep-preventing-my-com-dll-from-working)